# How to model this entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, scaffolding

I am creating an application for a shop, where clients are divided into two groups: receivers and payers.

1) Many receivers can be related to one same payer.
2) Payer can be receiver itself, thus he is related to one receiver only

My code so far look like this:

```
public class Receiver
{
    [Key]
    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PayerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Payer Payer { get; set; }
}

public class Payer
{
    [Key]
    public int PayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Receiver> Receivers { get; set; }
}
```

However I need to let the user create a new payer that is also a receiver at the same time, so the Receivers collection will have only one element. To do this I want to use a checkbox, which will be translated to a new column in the database (IsAlsoReceiver).

I am using MVC scaffolding for creating views, and it created two views for adding Receiver and another for adding Payer. When a user needs a Payer that is also a receiver he has to add entities in both views; can that be simplified in this scenario?

I am asking for a smart way to do so.

Comment: _"so the Receivers collection will be only with one element"_ makes no sense. That collection means "HAS receivers", you can't abuse it for "IS A receiver".

Comment: can receiver be related to multiple payer ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are missing an abstraction layer. When you build a project of a certain size (a size of which I think you have reached) you need each component (data layer, logic layer and views) to see different models.

The Data Access Layer (DAL) has Domain Models

The Logic Layer or API has Data Transfer Objects

The Views have View Models

To make it easy to build and to understand I'm just using Domain Models and View Models.

For your current problem I would build it like so:

```
//this is the view model
//The user sees this model
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsReceiver { get; set; }
    public bool IsPayer { get; set; }
}
//these are the domain models
//The database uses these models
public class Receiver {
    [Key]
    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int PayerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Payer Payer { get; set; }
}
public class Payer {
    [Key]
    public int PayerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Receiver> Receivers { get; set; }
}

public class AccountController {

    //create a view for the Person View Model
    //this is your abstraction
    public void SignUp(Person p) {
        //create models for the repository
        Payer payer = new Payer() {
            Name = p.Name
        };
        Receiver receiver = new Reciever() {
            Name = p.Name
        };

        //if the payer is his own receiver:
        Receiver.Payer = payer;

        //if the payer is his own receiver:
        Payer.Receivers.Add(receiver);


        //create for each depending upon some condition
        //I've just allowed the user to select whether he is a payer
        //based upon a checkbox on the form I suppose
        if (p.IsPayer) {
            db.Payers.Add(payer);
        }
        if (p.IsReceiver) {
            db.Receivers.Add(receiver);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no winning only degrees of losing :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say payer can also be a receiver, you don't mean that payer is its own receiver or do you ?

if YES then then you you can add the payer to its receiver in same action call and it makes sense to have only one item in list. it appears to be correct design.

if NO then you will need a second view to add the receiver, because a receiver is a different person. so in the payer page you should have a list of added receivers and a button to add receiver.

in any case your data model is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you say that the Payer can be Receiver as well, that already means that Receiver derives from Payer (because of the relational direction you mentioned).

So, you will end up having an inheritance like this:

```
class Payer 
{ 
}

class Receiver : Payer 
{
}
```

Relation between them (one-to-many from Payer-to-Receiver) is a self-referencing foreign key in the DB.

Take a look at the [inheritance support in the entity framework here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).

So, in your view, when the checkbox (isAlsoReceiver) is checked, you need to save Receiver, not a Payer. And it will be one entity that you have, not two.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can model this using single class and that will be simpler too. Below is my solution:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPayer { get; set; }
    public bool IsReceiver { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Receivers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but this db model adds possibility to have user that is both payer and receiver or neither of them